# Быстрая сортировка по убыванию на С

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, сортировка

Имею цель преобразовать исходный код быстрой сортировки по возрастанию, в точно такой же, но по убыванию.
Не совсем понимаю, как этот код работает (Получил на лекции)

```
int split(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int part_element = a[low];

    for (;;)
    {

        while (low < high && part_element <= a[high])
            high--;
        if (low >= high)
            break;
        a[low++] = a[high];

        while (low < high && a[low] <= part_element)
            low++;
        if (low >= high) break;
        a[high--] = a[low];
    }

    a[high] = part_element;

    return high;
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle;
    if (low >= high) return;
    middle = split(a, low, high);
    QuickSort(a, low, middle - 1);
    QuickSort(a, middle + 1, high);
}
```

Comment: Еще хак: оставить все как есть, а в конце добавить реверс массива.

Comment: Так еще в самом начале попробовал. Не прокатило:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как работает - просто рекурсивно делит каждый массив так, что после слева до некоторого элемента оказываются все элементы, меньшие его, а справа - большее. И так до массивов из 1 элемента.

А поменять саму сортировку просто - заменить два сравнения опорного элемента на обратные:

```
part_element <= a[high]
a[low] <= part_element
```

на

```
part_element >= a[high]
a[low] >= part_element
```

Comment: Можно ничего не менять, кстати. Вывод прямой или реверсный, вот и всё.